# ruby on rails I am trying to use find() to return a single result

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [I want to return a single result using .find() with Ruby on Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13521603/i-want-to-return-a-single-result-using-find-with-ruby-on-rails)

This is my code

```
<%= f.select :user_id, User.find(:user_id).collect {|t|
    [t.user_name, t.id]} %>
```

which gives the output

```
Couldn't find User with id=user_id
```

It doesn't seem to pass the variable instead it's passing 'user_id' as a string.

I just want it to return a single result into either a select list or label

I'm fairly new to ROR, I might be going about this the completely wrong way. Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are passing :user_id to the find method, which is a symbol, not a user id.

You have to pass a number to find, then find will search for the record with that id.

Another problem, why are you calling collect on the result of find ? Find return only one row, not an array.

Here is how you should structure your code :

You should get the user variable into the controller, for instance :

`@user = User.find(params[:id])`

Beware, find throws an exception if the model is not found, as you saw, consider using find_by_id that returns nil if no model is found.

Then, you can use @user in your view.

If you want to display a select tag with only the user in it, do the following :

`<%= f.select, :user_id, options_for_select([[@user.user_name, @user.id]]) %>`

Check http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html for form helpers.

Comment: Okay, so what is the var I want to pass?

Comment: Depends on how you want to get the data, see my edit.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation. It seems to be working for the 'edit view' but not for the 'new view'

Comment: For the new vew, your user does not exist yet, so you have to create it in your controller : `@user = User.new`

Comment: hmmm okay, I have a model with users. I was trying to get the current users ID and then display their name.

Comment: This is not really related to the current question, and i can't help you w/out code, maybe accept this answer and open a new question ?

Comment: That was my original question. I was using <%= f.select :user_id, User.find(:all).collect {|t|
        [t.user_name, t.id]} %> to find all of the users. If i just have <%= f.number_field :user_id %> it shows the current user ID so I thought I could do <%= f.select :user_id, User.find(:user_id).collect {|t|
        [t.user_name, t.id]} %> to just display the current user in a select list

Answer (score -1):

There is a method in ActiveRecord : @user = User.find_by_id(params[:id]) . It returns an instance object @user , on which you can call @user.name . The ruby convention is like this - if you pass @user to a method , that receives an ID as parameter , you don't have to write @user.id , Rails will understand you perfectly .

Comment: Actually the find() method does the same as find_by_id().

Comment: Nope, find() throws if no record is found, find_by_id() will return nil, slight difference !