# I want to return a single result using .find() with Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a user view and a rental view.
In my rental view im trying to show the current users name. I think I am pretty close but I can't work out this last bit.

This returns all of my users in a select list

```
<%= f.select :user_id, User.find(:all).collect {|t|
    [t.user_name, t.id]} %>
```

This returns my current users ID

```
<%= f.number_field :user_id %>
```

So I thought I could do something like

```
<%= f.select :user_id, User.find(:user_id).collect {|t|
    [t.user_name, t.id]} %>
```

Which I would want to only return the current user in a select list with their id as the value and their name in the list. If I do the above it tells me

```
Couldn't find User with id=user_id
```

So user_id is being passed as a literal string but I want to pass the user_id variable which should be somthing like 10. I don't know how to pass the user_id as a variable.

I'm fairly new to ROR, I might be going about this the completely wrong way. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Even if you passed an integer parameter to .find, you could not call .collect on the result, as a single User is not enumerable. You'd have to wrap the single object in an array, or re-think your solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming you have a rental object, for which you show the form, I assume it is an instance variable `@rental`, furthermore I assume that inside your `Rental` class there is the following relation

```
class Rental

  belongs_to :user

end
```

Then you could just write the following:

```
f.select :user_id, [[@rental.user.user_name, @rental.user.id]]
```

Hope this helps.

On a related but less important note: it is really weird to have a column called `user_name` for a `user`: I would call that column just `name`, since it is part of a user anyway.

Answer (score 0):

`find()` wants a variable, not a symbol. And `:all` probably isn't what you want. You should write a method in your controller like:

```
def user(u)
  @user = User.find(u)
end
```

Then call the method in the view or whatever like (I don't know exactly what you're trying to do here):

```
<% user(current_user.id) %>
```

Then you'll have a `@user` object with which you may play, i.e.:

```
<%= f.select :user_id, [[@user.name, @user.id]] %>
```

Answer (score 0):

I *think* you should be able to do:

```
<%= f.select :user_id, User.find(f.object.user_id).collect {|t| [t.user_name, t.id]} %>
```

This does seem a little odd to me though. I'd have thought either:

- Your object has a proper association to the relevant user, in which case you should be able to do `f.object.user.user_name` and `f.object.user.id`.
- If you genuinely want the currently logged in user, you should probably be asking your authentication framework/code for the reference. E.g. if you were using Devise, it would be `current_user`.

As an aside, I don't really understand why you want a select list just containing the current user - is that definitely what you're trying to achieve, or have I misunderstood?

Comment: Yeah, It might be a stupid way of accomplishing what I'm trying to do, but I'm learning... Symbols seem quite confusing to me.

Comment: @MaxRose-Collins yeah, they can be. Effectively a symbol is 'just a string'. The only difference is that whereas two strings with the same text will still be two separate objects, two symbols with the same text will be exactly the same object. When you're calling `f.number_field :user_id` for example, the `number_field` method has to go and lookup the value - the symbol just tells it where to look it up from. Make sense?